# Converting an object with numeric keys (possibly missing) to an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object with numeric keys that I would like to convert to an array. Trouble is, the keys may not be contiguous, i.e. some of the array elements may be missing. Is there some simple way to do this?

Example:

```
const raggedArrayObj = {"0": 10, "1": 3, "3": 5}
const raggedArray = toArray(raggedArrayObj) // [10, 3, , 5]
```

Comment: This use case is covered by [adiga’s answer](/a/57221894/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const raggedArrayObj = { "0": 10, "1": 3, "3": 5 };
const raggedArray = Object.assign([], raggedArrayObj);

console.log(raggedArray); // [10, 3, undefined, 5]
```

Comment: Arguably it's actually an empty index and not undefined

Comment: It's called sparse array.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov The index itself can be called “empty index”. Technically, on an Array object which has non-zero length _ℓ_, an “empty index” _k_ is just the lack of an own property, where the key of the property is the stringified integer _k_ with 0 ≤ _k_ ≤ min(_ℓ_ − 1, 2⁵³ − 1). The _array_ which has such an empty index can then be called “sparse array”.